# Creating list of objects from JSON fetch in React app

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm a bit stumped about how to go about this problem. I am trying to get data for ingredients for a specific recipe from my db and then display them in an ingredients component in my React app.

I get the data using a `fetch` call to my backend and it is easy enough to get the title and blurb for recipe using the following:

But when it comes to putting together the ingredient/quant/measure (which I assume would best be done via objects) I am lost. Just hoping for some assistance with this problem. Here is the JSON response:

```
0:
  id: 11
  ingredient_id: 11
  ingredient_name: "lemon"
  measure: "cups"
  quantity: "2"
  recipe_blurb: "Delicious"
  recipe_id: 6
  recipe_name: "Bolognese"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
1:
  id: 12
  ingredient_id: 12
  ingredient_name: "garlic"
  measure: "cloves"
  quantity: "5"
  recipe_blurb: "Delicious"
  recipe_id: 6
  recipe_name: "Bolognese"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
2:
  id: 13
  ingredient_id: 13
  ingredient_name: "butter"
  measure: "g"
  quantity: "500"
  recipe_blurb: "Delicious"
  recipe_id: 6
  recipe_name: "Bolognese"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Here is the React code:

```
export default function GetRecipe() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [recipeInfo, setRecipeInfo] = useState([])

//fetch
  const retrieveRecipe = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(name)
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/getjoinedrecipes/?name=${name}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((json) => {
        let result = json
        setRecipeInfo(result)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      [...]
      <div>
        <PageContainer
          recipeName={recipeInfo.length ? recipeInfo[0].recipe_name : ''}
          recipeBlurb={recipeInfo.length ? recipeInfo[0].recipe_blurb : ''}
          //insert method here
        ></PageContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Also if it is helpful - here is the `ingredientnamequant` component where the ingredients will end up - not sure how to dynamically create additional elements for each ingredient in the recipe...

```
import './IngredientNameQuant.css'

function IngredientNameQuant() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="ingredient-quantity"></div>
      <div className="ingredient-measure"></div>
      <div className="ingredient-name"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IngredientNameQuant
```

Comment: I don't understand your question? Do you need help rendering the object?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I need help putting the ingredients into objects with: ``ingredient_name``, ``quantity``, ``measure`` to render ingredients in a component. I am open to better ways to do this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to extract properties like ```ingredient_name```, ```quantity``` and ```measure``` and render those properties in a component?

Comment: Yes that is correct, presumably they would need to display the same amount of instances of the component as ingredients

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, seems to work:

```
let ingredientList = []
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          const ingObject = {
            name: result[i].ingredient_name,
            quantity: result[i].quantity,
            measure: result[i].measure,
          }
          ingredientList.push(ingObject)
```

Comment: The `for` loop can be rewritten to read ```const ingredientList = result.map(item => { return { name: item.ingredient_name, quantity: item.quantity, measure: item.measure  } })```.

Comment: Is this the proper way with react? I am not overly familiar with ``map`` so don't know its use cases that well.

Comment: React is just a JavaScript library, which uses all JavaScript methods. `Array.map` is a standard JavaScript method, and is indeed a proper way. In fact, `map`, `filter`, `forEach`, `some`, `every`, `reduce`, and other built-in Array methods are the most common and standard tools to handle data in React. See this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and perhaps give this [Syntax.fm podcast episode](https://syntax.fm/show/043/20-javascript-array-and-object-methods-to-make-you-a-better-developer) a listen about Array methods.